# AngularJS Dynamically Creating Select Box - ngModel Not Registering

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using one select box to conditionally generate a second select box. The select boxes populate correctly and everything looks okay in the Chrome Inspector on the elements.

The problem is the ng-model (ng-model="commandName" in the code example below) does not properly register the correct select value. So, if you look in the example, the {{commandName}} output at the end correctly outputs for the first select box but for the second select box nothing is output.

Is this a bug? Can anyone recommend an alternate method for approaching this problem?

Everything appears to work except commandName does not output anything in the p tag at the bottom but commandType does.

```
    <select ng-model="commandType" class="form-control" ng-init="commandType = ''; command = ''">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option ng-repeat="commandGroup in commandList" value="{{$index}}">{{commandGroup.name}}</option>
    </select>
    <!-- Shown if something is selected in the select box above -->
    <select ng-model="commandName" class="form-control" ng-if="commandType !== ''">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option ng-repeat="exactCommand in commandList[commandType].commands" value="{{$index}}">{{exactCommand.name}}</option>
    </select>
    <p>{{commandName}}</p>
```

AngularJS code:

```
$scope.initCommandList = function () {
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: $rootScope.webserver + 'admin/rterminalCommandList/',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
  }).success(function (data) {
    console.log("Command list");
    console.log(data.data);
    $scope.commandList = data.data;
  });
};
$scope.initCommandList();
```

And POST response:

```
{
  "data"
:
  [{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Application",
    "commands": [{
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Delete Smartcare data",
      "syntax": "su -c pm clear com.patasonic.android.smartcare",
      "comment": "Deletes Smartapp data"
    }]
  }, {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Bluetooth",
    "commands": [{
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Bluetooth Controls. Turn off",
      "syntax": "bluetooth@ off",
      "comment": "Turns off device bluetooth"
    }, {"id": 1, "name": "Bluetooth Controls. Turn on", "syntax": "bluetooth@ on", "comment": "Turn on bluetooth"}]
  }], "header"
:
  {
    "messages"
  :
    [], "response_code"
  :
    200
  }
}
```

Comment: can you post the angular code? cant do much with just this

Comment: okay.. added the angular code and the GET data used for generating the select inputs

Comment: wait so are you using ng-repeat to loop through the commandList and then assigning models based on what you're looping through? If so I think I might know what to do. Are you assigning anything to $scope.commandName anywhere in your controller?

Comment: no, just specifying it as the model for the second select

Comment: even when I add ng-init="commandName = 'test'" to the second select nothing shows up in the <p>{{commandName}}</p>

Comment: figured out that the ng-if messes the second model up

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use "select ng-options" instead of "option ng-repeat"
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

```
<select ng-model="myModel"
ng-options="command as command.name for command in commandList">
</select>
```

Here is a jsfiddle with an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/jcamelis/5y086ytr/4/

I hope it helps.